# React return array of components to render is not nesting properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have the following code in my React component render method

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
           <div>div1</div>
           <div>div2</div>
           {this.getOtherDivs()}
       </div>
    );
},

getOtherDivs: function() {
   return ([
       <div>div3</div>,
       <div>div4</div>       
   ]);
},
```

However, these two divs `div3` and `div4` are nested into single array instead of being separate.

When I do children.length for the top most div, I am getting 3 instead of 4.

I don't want to wrap the last two divs in an enclosing div.

Comment: I did a quick test using React v16.2.0 and both the pure HTML inspect and the React tab (from React DevTools) in Chrome show 4 divs inside another div. Can you provide details about how you are calling `children.length`? Where exactly does that come from? Also, what version of React are you using?

Comment: Your code should work

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`<React.Fragment />`](https://pawelgrzybek.com/return-multiple-elements-from-a-component-with-react-16/).

```
getOtherDivs: function() {
   return (
     <>
       <div>div3</div>
       <div>div4</div>
     </>       
   );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `map` to loop on the array and return the divs directly to main div

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
           <div>div1</div>
           <div>div2</div>
           {this.getOtherDivs().map(item => item)}
       </div>
    );
},
```

Comment: Why the `map` ?

Comment: `this.getOtherDivs()` already returns an array of React elements. `.map(item => item)` literally does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map`

Declare an array of items:

```
const items = [div3, div4];
```

Now your render method should look like:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
           <div>div1</div>
           <div>div2</div>
           {this.items.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
       </div>
    );
}
```

If you have an array of objects, then you can do it like this:

Declare an array of arrays:

```
const items = [[div3, div4],[div5, div6],[div7, div8]];
```

Then in your render method:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
           <div>div1</div>
           <div>div2</div>
           {this.items.map(item => 
               <div>
                   <div>item[0]</div>
                   <div>item[1]</div>
               </div>
           )}
       </div>
    );
}
```